# o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am new in spring. I am getting this error. o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed. Please Help me to fix this problem. And I'm using IntelliJ IDEA. Database using MongoDB.

Here is my log:

```
2024-02-23T16:02:46.887+05:30  WARN 11116 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'standardMongoSettingsCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration$MongoClientSettingsConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.StandardMongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer]: Factory method 'standardMongoSettingsCustomizer' threw exception with message: Failed looking up TXT record for host cluster0.xrb77cj.mongodb.net
2024-02-23T16:02:46.889+05:30  INFO 11116 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-02-23T16:02:46.895+05:30  INFO 11116 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-02-23T16:02:46.904+05:30 ERROR 11116 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'standardMongoSettingsCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration$MongoClientSettingsConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.StandardMongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer]: Factory method 'standardMongoSettingsCustomizer' threw exception with message: Failed looking up TXT record for host cluster0.xrb77cj.mongodb.net
```

My Pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.icbt</groupId>
    <artifactId>movies</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>movies</name>
    <description>A simple APIs related to movies</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: The actual error is shown in the log: `Failed looking up TXT record for host cluster0.xrb77cj.mongodb.net` Check the connection details. Probably in application.properties And check if you can connect to the database with other means (clients).